# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes after some time of use while Windows blue screens randomly and restarts every time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, freeze, recovery-mode

I have a dual booted system with Windows and Ubuntu.

I try to turn on my laptop and boot in windows and it just blue screens after a couple of minutes of use (no specific application, sometimes a game, sometimes just using firefox).

It also occasionally glitched out terribly with artifacts just frozen all over the screen and my inputs not showing any reaction.
If I remember correctly, it would display a different stop code every single time, one of them that I remember is "Attempted Write to Readonly Memory".

I ran a memory diagnostic and as it was restarting, it (might have) booted into ubuntu instead of windows because of my grub setup and sent me to an ubuntu installer for some reason (without any input from me, I wasn't really looking at my laptop at the time) and windows just stopped letting me in, crashing on boot every time and then instantly restarting.

I was really fed up so I decided to reinstall windows hoping that could fix anything. Didn't work and now windows crashes on boot.

Ubuntu has the issue of freezing up with artifacts frozen on the screen. I'm currently typing this out while in Ubuntu's recovery mode which surprisingly looks exactly like regular Ubuntu. I had thought that I would only have the command line interface to work with so this is a pleasant surprise as I can still get some work done.

I don't want to send my laptop out for repair considering it's quiz week and really need it right now.

Here's a picture of what windows looked like when it was frozen

[image: Here's a picture of what windows looked like when it was frozen]

All of these commands were run from recovery mode.

CPU:

```
$ lscpu

Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          16
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              8
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           104
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics
Stepping:                        1
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         439.720
CPU max MHz:                     4372.0000
CPU min MHz:                     400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        3593.23
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        4 MiB
L3 cache:                        8 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-15
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Not affected
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Mitigation; untrained return thunk; SMT enabled
                                  with STIBP protection
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_
                                 FW, STIBP always-on, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse s
                                 se2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtsc
                                 p lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpu
                                 id extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq mo
                                 nitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt
                                  aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy s
                                 vm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dn
                                 owprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perf
                                 ctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cp
                                 b cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb st
                                 ibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rd
                                 t_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsav
                                 eopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_ll
                                 c cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsa
                                 veerptr rdpru wbnoinvd cppc arat npt lbrv svm_l
                                 ock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid 
                                 decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vm
                                 save_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflo
                                 w_recov succor smca
```

Memory:

```
$ free -h

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           38Gi       3.1Gi        30Gi       121Mi       4.9Gi        34Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Comment: Since you have problems both with Windows and Ubuntu, I think you have a broken laptop. In other words the problem is in the hardware.

Comment: @user68186 That's really unfortunate, can I just run my laptop in Ubuntu's recovery mode for another month or so with no negative consequences?

Comment: No one can tell you when exactly the laptop will fail. I hope you have good sets of backup of your documents, photos, music, video, etc. Even if you do, copy your valuable data into an external drive for extra protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 right hands ( are able to do some technical work ) you can open your laptop and first clean it. Clean heatsinks, ventilator(s). Then you can try reseating your cable to your monitor. It will probably have some dust build up between cable and connections. If your a smokers clean everything with isopropal alcohol, as surfaces will be greasy and sticky. ( You can also do this if you not smoke/have a smoker in your house of course. )